# Debye's law to double solid's temperature

Tags: homework-and-exercises, thermodynamics, condensed-matter, solid-state-physics

Given Debye's law $ = ^3$ where $$ is characteristic of a material, I want to find the heat required to double a solid's temperature over the range where the law holds.
This was my reasoning:
$c=\frac{\Delta Q}{m \Delta T}$, so I can equate the two equations: $kT^3=\frac{\Delta Q}{m\Delta T}$ to find $\Delta Q$, getting $\Delta Q = km T^3 (2T-T)= km T^4$. However, the answer I should be getting is $\Delta Q = \frac{15}{4}k T^4$. Can anyone point me to what I am doing wrong?

Comment: No, just this. But yeah, that is one of the reasons why I am confused. I do not know whether by saying specific heat they meant molar specific heat rather than the actual specific heat. This is my first time encountering Debye's law so I am not sure on that side.

Comment: Regardless of this issue, I think the problem is that you should integrate. This would give the factor $15/4$.

Comment: Okay, that makes sense. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a derivative: $\frac{dQ}{dT} = kT^{3}$. You have to integrate from  the initial temperature $T_0$ to the double: $2T_0$.
$$ Q = k\int_{T_0}^{2T_0}T^{3}dT. $$ And you have the correct result.

Don't confuse heat capacity with specific heat capacity.

Comment: Oh, so Debye's law uses heat capacity, rather than specific heat capacity? It was specified that it was specific heat capacity though...

Comment: You can express it using both, they differ from a mass of the material. It's a constant.